# Cron does not start after container reboot

Tags: docker, server, cron, debian, containers

I have a docker container *Debian-based* where I run some cron processes. The container is launched with the `--restart` flag.

When the server in which docker is running is restarted, the cron tasks don't start. They are up again after the shell command `cron start` is typed.

I was looking to tackle this issue, so that cron is automatically started after every server reboot.

Answer (score -1):

you can add the command to the Dockerfile in order to make it work on restart:

```
CMD cron start && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

Comment: After adding this command to the Doker file, the resulting container continuously restart itself, and it is not possible to execute it in bash mode: ".....82c2142e is restarting, wait until the container is running"